# Conversion of xlsx to pandas DataFrame is only showng 71 columns, but I have 214 columns in xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

I have an xlsx file containing my personal data of business, I want to eliminate some rows from it. The xlsx file has 42 rows and 214 columns.

I am reading xlsx file with this method

```
df = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx') 
df
```

The Python code shows only 42 rows and 71 columns (**42 rows × 71 columns**) in jupyter lab.

I want to show all 42 rows and 214 columns in dataFrame

How can I do this?

Comment: The outpof of `print(df.shape)` ?

Comment: The output of print(df.shape) is (43, 71)

Comment: Thats confusing, can you inspect the last or first column that has been read in? Thinking all data from columns 71-214 could be inside that one column?